# customize error message in django-allauth

Tags: django-allauth

How can I customizs error message in django-allauth?

I already implement overriding input forms for login

and it does work very well.

but, i want to build new error message when password mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% on this, but I believe you would have to make a custom form to do that. If you look into the directory: `lib/allauth/account/forms.py` in your project you should see all of the forms with their default error messages. It's bad practice to edit this file directly so you would have to make a custom form with the error messages you would like.